# Data type issue in aggregation in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

I have written following code for aggregation of two tables in php application

```
    $lookupTwo = array(
        '$lookup'=> array(
            "from" => "studentTbl",
            "localField" => "studentDetailId",
            "foreignField" => "studentId",
            "as" => "recieverDetails"
        )
    );
```

Now I am facing an issue, the `studentDetailId` field is stored as a string and  `studentId` is stored as an integer.

The above query will return empty result.

- Is there any possibility for performing aggregation in such case?

Comment: No there is not. You need to convert the type. The aggregation framework cannot "cast" values between types.

Comment: Thanks for the answer